# Is pstp2reclaim.com legit company or not

Tags: scam

I lost approximately $15,000 with my brother in an investment in a crypto scam. I have filed a complaint with the SEC and the broker is currently not responding to me. The whole thing is shady and he probably won’t give me a refund. It was stupid, we shouldn’t have been so careless.

There are some companies out there that claim to help with this kind of thing, but my friend suggested PSTP Reclaims and I have read specifically about this company but I don’t want to get burned again so what is your opinion is this legit company or not.